Can an arbitrary path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be parametrized as $f(t)\hat{u}$ for a basis vector of some arbitrary coordinate system?
This question comes from a recent question in Physics SE I answered, link. This has sparked a question I don't have the background to answer. Consider some arbitrary path in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Some of these paths have fairly obvious parametrizations in the form $f(t)\hat{u}$ for some basis vector of an appropiate coordinate system. This can be done with any straight line, for example. However, what about an arbitrary path? Can any arbitrary path be written as $f(t)\hat{u}$ for an appropiate coordinate system?
I guess an equivalent statement would be: is an arbitrary path in the $\mathbb{R}^3$
vector space always a one dimensional subspace or not?

There is something about your question that I don't understand. The symbol $\hat u$ appears to be a fixed vector independent of the $t$ parameter. If that is the intention, then $f(t) \hat u$ always lies on the straight line through the origin parallel to $\hat u$, which surely contradicts the visceral fact that squiggly wiggly curves exist.

Assuming you mean $\hat u$ to be a function of $t$ like Lee Mosher asks, if the curve $\vec f(t)$ isn't space filling then I think it is within the spirit of the question to move the origin so that $\vec f(t) \ne 0$ for all $t$. Then $$\vec f(t) = |\vec f(t)|\frac{\vec f(t)}{|\vec f(t)|}$$ which either answers the question or at least reduces it to a question about paths on the unit sphere.

To the question:

Is an arbitrary path in the R3 vector space always a one dimensional subspace or not?

No, an arbitrary curve does not follow the properties needed to be considered a subspace.
However, to the larger question, this is very commonly done in differential geometry. We can look every point on the path and make the tangent vector a basis vector of a basis. Call this $\textbf{T}$ and choose two other basis vectors to make it a complete basis. Then, as you move along the path, your basis vectors will change the direction, but your path will always be along $\textbf{T}$. In fact, $\textbf{T}$ is the tangent vector and the other two basis vectors can tell you how $\textbf{T}$ changes. This can be done by the Frenet-Serret Equations.

Thank you, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Glad I could help! :)
